# how to add JRParagraph.DEFAULT_TAB_STOP_WIDTH before fill the report in Jasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm generating jrxml file dynamically based on the user input and try to fill the report.
It works fine for some cases. When user adding more columns system throws the following exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ParagraphUtil.getFirstTabStop(ParagraphUtil.java:208) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderNextLine(TextMeasurer.java:1009) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.renderParagraph(TextMeasurer.java:717) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.TextMeasurer.measure(TextMeasurer.java:416) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextElement.chopTextElement(JRFillTextElement.java:504) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.prepare(JRFillTextField.java:593) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.prepareElements(JRFillElementContainer.java:328) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:377) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.fill(JRFillBand.java:351) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2039) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:771) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportContent(JRVerticalFiller.java:301) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:148) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:634) 
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:956)
```

I'm using *JasperReports 4.7* library.

Following is the java code for fill & export the jrxml.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;

    JExcelApiExporter  apiExporter = null;
    HashMap map = new HashMap();
    JRSwapFileVirtualizer virtualizer = null;

    try {

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(jasperFilePath);

        if (reportType.equals("REPORTGENERATOR")) {
            map.put(JRParameter.IS_IGNORE_PAGINATION, Boolean.TRUE);            
        }

        map.put("REALPATH", realPath);

        String directory = realPath+"tempdocs";
        JRSwapFile swapFile = new JRSwapFile(directory, 1024, 100);
        virtualizer = new JRSwapFileVirtualizer(50, swapFile, true);
        map.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, virtualizer);               
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(inputStream, map, resultSetDataSource);


        apiExporter = new JExcelApiExporter();
        apiExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        apiExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        apiExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
        apiExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        apiExporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, 
                realPath + "tempdocs/jasper/" + reportName + ".xls");


        apiExporter.exportReport();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }finally{
        try{
            if (virtualizer != null) virtualizer.cleanup();
            inputStream.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Suggest me the good way to handle this issue.

Comment: You should post the relevant *Java* code to reproduce the issue

Comment: And what is the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replace the tab character by blank space using `replace(col,chr(9),' ')` in each varchar column of my query. now it's working fine.
but i know this is not a correct answer. this is just a work around solution.